# how can I move cursor at any position after editing text at paragraph contenteditable in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have contenteditable paragraph where I can write specific words which will automatically be colored . But when I try to edit already colored text my cursor position moves backward so how can I put my cursor at current position while editing already colored text.

my html code:-

```
<p contenteditable="true" id="ide" style="border:1px solid red;" >...</p>
```

my js code:-

```
<script>
  function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement)
   {
      var range,selection;
      if(document.createRange)
       {


        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);
        range.collapse(false);
        selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);

       }else if(document.selection){ 


         range = document.body.createTextRange();
         range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);
         range.collapse(false);
         range.select();

      }
   }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ide").bind('keyup',function(){
           var x = $(this).text();
           color(x)
           setEndOfContenteditable(this);
        });
    });

  function color(c){
     var str = c; 
    var res = str.replace(/hello|house|car|happy/gi, function myFunction(x)
      {
      return '<span style="color:red;">'+x+'</span>';});
      document.getElementById("ide").innerHTML = res;
      }
```

Many people who try this can say this is correct but please try by typing  hello or house or car or happy on contenteditable paragraph it will be automatically colored now go back to edit that colored string.

demo:-  https://jsbin.com/nodome/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

So, your question is a little bit *misleading*, your problem is `keyup` event on <kbd>⟵</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> arrow keys or <kbd>Select+All</kbd>, after every `keyup` your function trying to detect word and execute `color()`, so if you use `keypress` event you can avoid this.

```
$("#ide").bind('keypress', function() {
  var x = $(this).text();
  color(x)
  setEndOfContenteditable(this);
});
```

But if you want to execute `color()` after `keyup` you need to detect which `key` pressed and exclude `arrow` keys.

**[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/zecapodaku/1/edit?html,output)**

Comment: that was correct but it dosn't work while editing again position changes

Comment: @AlishaSharma Hmm.. let me check again and update my answer

Comment: @AlishaSharma Well, `setEndOfContenteditable()` made this problem, can you explain why you used such `function` *I mean create `createRange`* ?

Comment: when I type each word I need to detect  that word and make decision whether to color that word or not and  I Need to  push that  text back to <p> that is why my cursor moves forward to keep Cursor at  end  after replacing typed content back to <p> I have used setEndOfContenteditable() if you have any other idea  then you can use it